# For loop that doesn't iterate completely but displays no error message

Tags: c#, for-loop, random

I have a simple program that uses Random and a for loop to generate two six-digit numbers. The loop generates two numbers every time and most of the time both numbers are six digits. Sometimes, though, one of those numbers is less than 6 digits (4 to 5 digits). It generates no error message in all cases. What's going on? I've posted all the code although some of it is unused/tested until I can figure out the Random problem.

The  six-digit number starts as an empty string. Random generates an integer, the integer gets converted to string then += onto six-digit number string, which is converted to an integer when the method finishes.

The rest of the program is unimplemented and will involve extracting the 2nd, 4th, and 6th place digits in each number and adding them all together. The troubling thing is the Random issue.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Numbers theNumbers = new Numbers();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", theNumbers.Ints[0]));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", theNumbers.Ints[1]));
}
```

Numbers class

```
class Numbers
{
    public int[] Ints { get; set; }


    public Numbers()
    {
        Ints = new int[5];

        CreateTheFirstTwoNumbers(new RandomNummberGenerator());

    }

    public int[] CreateTheFirstTwoNumbers(RandomNummberGenerator RNG) 
    {
        for (int arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < 2; arrayIndex++)
        {
            Ints[arrayIndex] = RNG.CreateRandomNumber();
        }

        return Ints;
    }
```

Random Number Generator class

```
class RandomNummberGenerator
{
    public Random  Generator { get; set; }

    public RandomNummberGenerator()
    {
        Generator = new Random();
    }

    public int CreateRandomNumber()
    {
        string number = "";

        for (int numberIndex = 0; numberIndex < 6; numberIndex++)
        {
            number += Generator.Next(0, 10).ToString();
        }

        return int.Parse(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Only include the code _relevant_ to your issue, these `//unused` comments indicate to me that there is code not being used, so remove it from your question

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. In order to maximize your chances of getting help, please try to provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you're encountering

Comment: @aGuy You could seed your Generator so that it produces only 6 digit numbers, by doing `Generator.Next(100000, 1000000)`, is there a reason you can't just get a random 6 digit number instead of getting random number 0 - 9 and appending them together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a much easier (more correct, and certainly requiring less code) solution to generating a random number, and converting it to a 6-character string

```
var rng = new Random();
var number = rng.Next(1000000); // generates a number between 0 and 999999 
                                // (maxValue is exclusive upper bound)
var numberAsString = number.ToString("000000");
```

If the number can not start with leading zeroes, generate a random number between 100000 and 999999:

```
var number = rng.Next(100000, 1000000);
```

Comment: +1, but I think the second argument to `Next()` should be 1000000 rather than 999999, as that argument is [an exclusive upper bound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You're generating a six-character string where each character is a digit from 0-9, inclusive, and then parsing that string as an integer. If the first character is `'0'`, then you'll have a number with five digits (or fewer if there are more leading zeroes). If you want to guarantee a six-digit number, then your first digit should be 1-9 instead of 0-9.

If you haven't seen it already, I'd recommend reading Eric Lippert's blog post on [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

You won't get an error message unless you made a syntax mistake. Most likely you have a semantic error. If I had to guess, I would say your first digit is occasionally be generated as a zero.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you convert the generated number to `int` .

Your `CreateRandom()` function sometimes create numbers started by `0(zero)` so when you convert to a numeric type as int, float and etc.. the zero on the left is ignored.

So, if you generate `012345` when you convert to int you will get `12345`, because the 0 on the left is supressed.

If you want a six digit number, be sure the first digit its not `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is actually working. You get numbers with less digits when the leading digits are `0`.

You can force the display of six digits by using the following formatting

```
string s = number.ToString("000000");
```

E.g., with `123` the result is `"000123"`.

Output with:

```
string s = String.Join(", ", theNumbers.Ints.Select(i => i.ToString("000000")).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(s);
```